# iOS 11 UIAlertview not show full Message

Tags: objective-c, ios11, uialertview

I try to make a Popup for my app with UIAlertView. This Popup display fine on iOS 10 or older but on iOS 11 it doesn't display all the content of the popup. What can I do to fix that error!? 
And this is the code that I am using to make the custom `UAlertView`. Any ideas?

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ok", nil) otherButtonTitles: nil];

UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 900, 900)];

[lbl setAttributedText:getPopUp];

[lbl setNumberOfLines:0];

[lbl sizeToFit];

[lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-popup-2.png"]]];

    [alert setValue:lbl forKey:@"accessoryView"];

    [alert show];
```

[image: Click here to see example]

Sorry for my poor English! 
Regards! thanks for all your help!!

Comment: forget about UIAlertView. it has been deprecated. use UIAlertController

Comment: Please use UIAlertController for showing the alert message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UIAlertController` instead of `UIAlertView`.

```
  UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:title //alert Title
                                 message:getPopUp //Your Message
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIView *firstSubview = alert.view.subviews.firstObject;
    UIView *alertContentView = firstSubview.subviews.firstObject;
    for (UIView *subSubView in alertContentView.subviews) {
      subSubView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-popup-2.png"]];
     }

   UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                        {
                            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                        }];


   [alert addAction:ok];

   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope this will help you.
For more details: http://hayageek.com/uialertcontroller-example-ios/

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I have designed to insert image and set paragraph style for my message and it works fine on ios 10 or older. It is very complicated to switch to UIAlertController. Can you fix my own code? I think it only lacks a small setup code

Comment: @TháiSalem please check my updated answer. Hope this will help.

Comment: My Message (getPopUp) is an AttributedString and I use Label to display it with UIAlertView. How can i display it with UIAlertController? Tks

Comment: Where `getPopUp` will place? Is it in title or message?

Comment: I have shown it with the command [alert.view addSubview:label] (in this label i set [label setAtributedString:getPopUp] . thank you very much again

Answer (score 2):

UIAlertView has been deprecated. Instead of using UIAlertView you should use UIAlertController like this :-

```
 UIAlertController *alertController=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
 UIAlertAction *actionOk=[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        //Ok Button Code
    }];
  UIAlertAction *actionCancel=[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        //Cancel Button Code
    }];
  [alertController addAction:actionOk];
  [alertController addAction:actionCancel];

  [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I have designed to insert image and set paragraph style for my message and it works fine on ios 10 or older. It is very complicated if switch to UIAlertController. Can you fix my own code?